# data is not getting stored in Firebase Database when enter data ins sign up page

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

data is not stored in when i add values in my sign up form
here is the error

Error: Assertion failed: file:///G:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.2/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:273:11
options != null
"FirebaseOptions cannot be null when creating the default app."

xception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following JSNoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')

here is the code

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:fchat/CompleteProfile.dart';
import 'package:fchat/UserModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SignUpPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SignUpPage> createState() => _SignUpPageState();

}
var signup;
class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {

  TextEditingController emailController=TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController=TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController cpasswordController=TextEditingController();

  void checkValues() {
    String email = emailController.text.trim();
    String password = passwordController.text.trim();
    String cpassword = cpasswordController.text.trim();

    if (email == "" || password == "" || cpassword == "") {
      print("plz filled all the field");
    }

    else if (password != cpassword) {
      print("password did not Match");
    }


    else {
      signup(email, password);
    }


    void Signup(String email, String password) async {
      UserCredential? credential;


     try {
        credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword
          (email: email, password: password);
      }
      on FirebaseAuthException catch (ex) {
        print(ex.code.toString());
      }

            if (credential != null) {
        String uid = credential.user!.uid;
        UserModel newUser = UserModel(
          uid: uid,
          email: email,
          fullname: "",
          profilepic: "",

        );

        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(uid).set
          (newUser.toMap()).then((value){
          print("new user will created");
        });
      }
    }
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 40,
          ),
          child: Center(

            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [


                  Text("Chat App", style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme
                          .of(context)
                          .colorScheme
                          .secondary,
                      fontSize: 40,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                  ),),

                  SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  TextField(
                    controller: emailController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Email Adresss"
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10,),

                  TextField(
                    controller: passwordController,
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Password"
                    ),
                  ),


                  SizedBox(height: 10,),

                  TextField(
                    controller: cpasswordController,
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Confirm Password"
                    ),
                  ),


                  SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  CupertinoButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                   checkValues();
                   /*   Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                       builder:(context)
                      {
                        return CompleteProfile();
                      }
                      ),
                      );
                      */


                    },

                    color: Theme
                        .of(context)
                        .colorScheme
                        .secondary,
                    child: Text("Sign Up"),

                  ), // CupertinoButton


                ],
              ),
            ), // SingleChildscrollView

          ),
        ),
      ),


      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("Already have an account?", style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16
            ),), // Textstyle // Text
            CupertinoButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text("Log in", style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16
              ),), // TextStyle // Text
            ), // CupertinoButton
          ],
        ), // Row
      ), // Container


    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you initialize Firebase anywhere? If so, can you edit your question to show that code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize Firebase in your `main.dart`.

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // THIS:

  await Firebase.initializeApp( 
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  ...
}
```

**firebase_options.dart**

```dart
class DefaultFirebaseOptions {
  static FirebaseOptions get currentPlatform {
     
     // SIMPLIFIED CODE

     return webProduction;
  }

  static const FirebaseOptions webProduction = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'xxx',
    appId: 'xxx',
    messagingSenderId: 'xxx',
    projectId: 'xxx',
    authDomain: 'xxx.firebaseapp.com',
    storageBucket: 'xxx.appspot.com',
    measurementId: 'xxx',
  );
```